# How can I use a file in my plugin as a replacement for single.php on custom-post-type query?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, templates

I am creating a Custom Post Type using a custom plugin. One of the requirement of the custom post type is to be presented in a table layout for print / email purpose.

It seems that the logical solution for this situation is to include a specific template file in the plugin which will be used on single Custom Post Type query instead of the single.php / index.php provided in the theme.

How can I use a file in my plugin as a replacement for single.php / index.php on single custom-post-type query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I handle these is to store to use `template_include` to conditionally pass my plug-in template. One of these conditions is that the corresponding file hasn't already been found by WordPress (i.e. isn't present in the theme folder).

This means that users can over-ride the plug-in template with a theme-specific one by simply creating the appropriate template in their theme. As such they can make alterations and not worry about plug-in updates:

The following uses `single-event.php` instead of `single.php` when viewing a single post of 'event' post type.

```
/**
 * Checks to see if appropriate templates are present in active template directory.
 * Otherwises uses templates present in plugin's template directory.
 */
add_filter('template_include', 'wpse72544_set_template');
function wpse72544_set_template( $template ){

    /* 
     * Optional: Have a plug-in option to disable template handling
     * if( get_option('wpse72544_disable_template_handling') )
     *     return $template;
     */

    if(is_singular('event') && 'single-event.php' != $template ){
        //WordPress couldn't find an 'event' template. Use plug-in instead:
        $template = 'absolute/path/to/plugin/template/single-event.php';
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Note that all the main query conditionals (`is_*` functions) are available to you at this point.